# Ingame Timer Doesnt Restart Counting after its counted till limit once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, countdown

I am creating a quiz game that has a timer for every question.I tried to create a script that counts down from 20 to 0 and after that the game shows the correct answer with a soundeffect and then goes to the next question, However whenever I start the game it seems to works exactly as planned only for the first question and after it resets to 20 it stays there.Cant really seem to find what the problem is.

```
public class TimerSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Component")]
    public TextMeshProUGUI timerText;


    [Header("Timer Settings")]
    public float currentTime; //this is set to 20

    [Header("Limit Settings")]
    public bool hasLimit;
    public float timerLimit; //this is set to 0

    public GameObject answerAbackblue;
    public GameObject answerAbackgreen;
    public GameObject answerBbackblue;
    public GameObject answerBbackgreen;
    public GameObject answerCbackblue;
    public GameObject answerCbackgreen;
    public AudioSource incorrectSFX;
    public GameObject answerA;
    public GameObject answerB;
    public GameObject answerC;




    private void Update()
    {
        
        
            currentTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            

            if (currentTime <= 5)
            {
                timerText.color = Color.red;
            }

            if (hasLimit && (currentTime <= timerLimit))
            {
                currentTime = 0f;
                SetTimerText();
                enabled = false;
                if (QuestionGenerate.actualAnswer == "A")
                {
                    answerAbackgreen.SetActive(true);
                    answerAbackblue.SetActive(false);
                    incorrectSFX.Play();
                }
                else if (QuestionGenerate.actualAnswer == "B")
                {
                    answerBbackgreen.SetActive(true);
                    answerBbackblue.SetActive(false);
                    incorrectSFX.Play();
                }
                else
                {
                    answerCbackgreen.SetActive(true);
                    answerCbackblue.SetActive(false);
                    incorrectSFX.Play();
                }
            StartCoroutine(NewQuestion());

                

            }

            SetTimerText();
        


        
    }

    private void SetTimerText()
    {
        timerText.text = currentTime.ToString("0.0");
    }

    

    IEnumerator NewQuestion()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        answerAbackgreen.SetActive(false);
        answerBbackgreen.SetActive(false);
        answerCbackgreen.SetActive(false);
        answerAbackblue.SetActive(false);
        answerBbackblue.SetActive(false);
        answerCbackblue.SetActive(false);
        answerA.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        answerB.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        answerC.GetComponent<Button>().enabled = true;
        QuestionGenerate.displayingQuestion = false;
        QuestionGenerate.score++;
        timerText.color = Color.white;
        currentTime = 20f;
        timerText.text = currentTime.ToString("0.0");
    }

}
```

Comment: By the looks of it you disable the whole script when timer surpasses limit, but you don't reenable it inside the coroutine, so update is no longer called afterwards.

Comment: yes I actually found that out shortly after.Thanks so much much appreciated :P